# rxJava buffering by signal

Tags: java, rx-java2

I want to use buffering by signal using rxJava as described [here](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%203%20-%20Taming%20the%20sequence/5.%20Time-shifted%20sequences.md#buffer-by-signal) but based on timestamps of objects instead of fixed intervals. If minutes would be used as signal, then the desired result would look like this:

`2018-03-26 19:14:13
2018-03-26 19:14:44
2018-03-26 19:14:59
---- signal ----
2018-03-26 19:15:23
2018-03-26 19:15:27
---- signal ----
2018-03-26 19:16:01
2018-03-26 19:16:04
2018-03-26 19:16:40
2018-03-26 19:16:45`

I've spent an entire day on this but I cannot get it to work. This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881227/rxjava-buffer-items-until-some-condition-is-true-for-current-item) but the code in the accepted answer seems for an older version of rxJava. I've also found another [solution](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersbufferuntil) but with this it's also not possible to check a previous value.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49301758/61158

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The answer for completeness sake, but credit goes fully to [akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd). Thanks again!

```
OffsetDateTime baseDateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(2018, 3, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    Observable
        .fromArray(
            baseDateTime.plusNanos(1),
            baseDateTime,
            baseDateTime,
            baseDateTime.plusMinutes(1),
            baseDateTime.plusMinutes(1).plusNanos(1),
            baseDateTime.plusMinutes(1),
            baseDateTime.plusMinutes(2).plusNanos(1),
            baseDateTime.plusMinutes(2),
            baseDateTime,
            baseDateTime.plusNanos(1),
            baseDateTime.plusMinutes(4),
            baseDateTime.plusMinutes(4).plusNanos(1)
        )
        .compose(bufferUntilChanged(dateTime -> dateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

private static <T, K> ObservableTransformer<T, List<T>> bufferUntilChanged(Function<T, K> keySelector) {
    return o -> o.publish(q -> q.buffer(q.distinctUntilChanged(keySelector).skip(1)));
}
```